# Calculating average by using where or having clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table T1 looks like:

```
acctid  time transactid  amnt
 233    xxx    2         400
```

I want to return all the transaction with amnt > the average(amnt) in the table. Here is my code:

```
select * from (select transactid,amnt,avg(amnt) 
over (partition by transactid) avgamnt from T1) where amnt>avg(mnt)
over (partition by transactid)
```

However, I am thinking another one using having clause

```
select * from (select transactid,amnt,avg(amnt) 
    over (partition by transactid) avgamnt from T1) having amnt>avg(mnt)
    over (partition by transactid)
```

May I ask which one is better(or correct) and why please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to return all the transaction with amnt > the average(amnt) in
>   the table.

so why not use this:

```
select * from T1 where T1.amnt > (select avg(t.amnt) from T1 t)
```

Comment: Hello, farheg. Thanks a lot for your reply. I use this example just to know the difference between "having" and "where" clause. Which way is correct please?

Comment: you are welcome, "having" is for when we want apply some conditions on aggregated columns. and we may use both "where" and "having" in queries. also which be simpler and faster, it's the better.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is almost there:

```
select *
from (select transactid, amnt,
             avg(amnt) over (partition by transactid) as avgamnt 
      from T1
     ) t
where amnt > avgamnt;
```

You define the column in the subquery.  Then, you just have to use it.

Comment: May I ask that which one of answer can run please?

Comment: @user4441082 you told: I want to return all the transaction with amnt > the average(amnt) **in the table**. so you don't need partition over transactionId

Comment: Thanks both for your answer. I have one last question. In Gordon's answer, If I don't use 't' alias in line 5, will the code still run please?

Comment: @user4441082 . . . In Oracle, the table alias on a subquery is optional.  Most other databases require it.